# c#: Why Validator omitts a ValidationAttribute validation if multiple ValidationAttribute are present?

Tags: c#, validation

I have a simple WPF-Application and I use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator to validate data.

I've created a custom ValidationAttribute which I can set multiple times on a member (AllowMultiple=True).

Simplified something like that:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    [CustomValidationAttribute("para bla bla")] // as first
    [CustomValidationAttribute("para blu blu")] // as second
    public string MemberA { get; set; }
}
```

When I now perform Validator.TryValidate(..., true) only the second attribute ("blu blu") is validated, the first, in a magical way, is omitted.

Do I miss something?
Or is this a feature? If so, who can I get rid of it?

Thank you for your ideas.

**[EDIT 2019-03-12 17:10 CET]**

Even when I add an attribute extra, only the validation of the the last one is executed.

```
public class SampleClass
{
    [CustomValidationAttribute("para bla bla")] // as first
    [CustomValidationAttribute("para blu blu")] // as second
    [CustomValidationAttribute("para bibi")] // as thrid
    public string MemberA { get; set; }
}
```

"Bibi" is validated, the others not ...
Strange, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe the first one is overloaded with the second custom validator?

Comment: @GabrielCostin Not sure if I understand you correctly: You assume, the first attribute is replaced with the second one?

Comment: Yes that's what I am assuming, in fact you can try with another attribute, for exemple `StringLength` , define 2 or more attributes and check the output

Comment: Confirmed: The behavior is, that only the last declared validation attribute each type is used for validation. This knowledge is nice, but back to topic: How can I change that behavior? I find it very strange, that same-type-attributes are just swallowed, up instead an aproppriate exception is thrown ...

Comment: Well I am not that experienced to offer you a very good solution , what I would do is just like create that `CustomValidationAttribute` and maybe instead of having a `string` as parameter type I would go for an `array` of strings or whatever

Comment: Yes, as a workaround I can adjust my custom attribute (and rebuild the ones which I don't have the source ...). But still I'm curious about that behavior. So, with permission, I would let this case open - may be someone has an explanation, which to learn about, I'm quite interested :)